# build a Form with InputTextField and DropDownMenu

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

please I want to build a Form widget including both TextFormFields and DropDownButton in Flutter, can someone help me to show what is the appropriate way to do that ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check below an example of TypeAhead with Form.

https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_typeahead

```
TypeAheadField(
  getImmediateSuggestions: false,
  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
    autofocus: false,
    controller: _typeAheadFullTextController,  
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Enter keyword.",
      //  suffixIcon: 
        )
     ),
  suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {},
  itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(suggestion),
    );
  },
  onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
  },
);
```

Comment: is this Flutter ?

Comment: Yes. in flutter.